# VMWare Server vs. VMWare Player

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-10.04, vmware-player

I have a lot of experience with VMWare Player but when I tried VMWare server I couldn't get anywhere with it. I want to try it again on Ubuntu 10.04. How is it different from Player? If I want to use it to run Windows inside Linux, and log into it from the host computer, can I use server for that? How does it work? Do I just RDP or VNC into the virtual machine? I remember that it doesn't give the host computer a graphical interface like Player does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only used VMWare server on Windows, so I hope this translates to the Linux version as well. The Server edition has a remote web control interface if I remember correctly. While VMWare player can, to my knowledge (maybe it changed) not edit virtual machines, server should be able to do so without a problem. Also, Server can run headless, so it can run in background without having a GUI openend all the time (Which is interesting if you have Linux Virtual machines without GDM or equivalent installed). Hope that helps.

Comment: So if it's running in the background without a GUI, how do you access the OS inside the VM from the host machine? Like if I'm on Linux and I want to play a game in Windows, how do I get into the Windows OS?

Comment: @awake, you either RDP into the VM, or you connect to the web GUI through a browser and open a console session.

Comment: http://www.vmware.com/products/server/faqs.html

Comment: If you connect through a web browser doesn't that have an effect on performance?

Comment: @awake, the management console is web based.  There is no impact on performance.  Really, the link I provided does a pretty good job of giving an overview.  I've used VMware Server briefly in the past, and it did a good job.  Like private_meta said, VMServer gives you the ability to create and modify VMs unlike Player.